# docker container unable to find files from within the container

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, centos7

I'm using docker to find a few files on the host volume and modify them directly.
The docker container run time is unable to find file{s} in the host volume, shared through `-v <path>:<path>:z`.

However, when I run the container using `docker run -it ... myimage /bin/bash` mode this finds the files without any issues.

The entire setup described is being run through a Jenkins job.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

COPY ./run-find.sh /
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/run-find.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/run-find.sh"]
CMD ["${FIND_DIR}"]
```

My run-find.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
echo "Find dir: $FIND_DIR"
set -e
mapfile -t files_list < <(find "$FIND_DIR" -type f ! -name "*.asc" \
    ! -name "*.sha1" \
    ! -name "*.sh" \
    ! -name "_remote.repositories" \
    ! -name "*.lastUpdated")
# Can list the file unsing ls
ls ${SIGN_DIR} -la

if [ "${#files_list[@]}" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: No files in map. Quitting..."
    exit 1
else
   echo "processing file list"
fi
```

Build the image:

```
docker build -f /w/Dockerfile \
      --build-arg FIND_DIR=${FIND_DIR} \
      -t myimage ${WORKSPACE}
```

Run the container as follows:

```
docker run -e KEY1="${KEY1}" -e PASS="${PASS}" \
          -u root:root \
          -e MY_CONFIG=${MY_CONFIG} \
          -v /w:/w:z \
          myimage /run-find.sh "${FIND_DIR}"
```

What am I missing? I get the following output and find is unable to find the files in the dir, however, I can list it with an ls or list the files when I do a test run.

output:

```
+ docker run -e KEY=test-key -e PASS=/w/pass -u root:root -e CONFIG=/w/my-config.conf -v /w:/w:z -v /home/jenkins:/home/jenkins:z myimage /run-find.sh /w/repo
FIND_DIR: /w/repo
+ echo 'FIND_DIR: /w/repo'
+ set -e
+ pwd
+ ls /w/repo -la
/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 2 1000 1000 4096 May 20 08:01 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 1000 1000 4096 May 20 08:03 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 1000 1000    8 May 20 08:01 test.pom
+ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
+ cd /w/repo
+ ls
test.pom
+ mapfile -t files_list
++ find . -type f
ERROR: No files in map. Quitting...
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'ERROR: No files to sign. Quitting...'
+ exit 1
```

Comment: what happens if you pull the `find` command out and run it so the output gets printed to the console? This will tell you if the problem is with `find` not finding the files, or the `mapfile`.

Comment: This works perfectly when run manually on the host and in the container. I'm guessing this has something todo with the permissions or the docker context. You can see the output of the ls command shows the file names.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in question is not related to the dockerfile or bach script itself, however, it's because scripts required an extra set of curly braces. When passing the parameters to shell scripts, you would need to escape curly braces or they would simply get replaced with a `0` in the script which is not easy to debug through the job console.

More detailed explanation can be found in [here](https://docs.releng.linuxfoundation.org/projects/global-jjb/en/latest/best-practices.html#passing-parameters-to-shell-scripts)